# Convert ArrayList of Objects to Two dimensional Array

Tags: java, arrays, string, object, arraylist

I am having a little trouble converting an Arraylist of objects to a two dimensional array. The arrayList ar contains a number of objects named Row. Each Row contains a number of Strings. I want to be able to go through the arrayList, access each Row and store the Strings inside in an array. I'm really sorry if that doesn't make sense. I'm even finding it hard to explain!
Here is what i have so far:

```
public String tableArray[][]; //Array of every applicant
private ArrayList<Row> ar;
private Row r;

public void display()
{
int i, j;
for (Row r: ar)
    i = 0;
    for(String s: r)
    {
        tableArray = new String[i][j];
        j++;
    }
    i++;
}
```

here is the Row class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.lang.String;

public class Row
{   
private String appNumber;
private String name;
private String date;
private String fileLoc;
private String country;
private String elementString;
public String results[];

public Row(String appNumber, String name, String date, String fileLoc, String country, Table table)
{
    this.appNumber = appNumber;
    this.name = name;
    this.date = date;
    this.fileLoc = fileLoc;
    this.country = country;
    asAString();
    table.addApplicant(this);

}

public void asAString()
{
    String elementString = appNumber +","+ name +","+ date +","+ fileLoc +","+ country;
    results = elementString.split(",");}
}
```

Thanks for the help guys

Comment: Show us the definition of the Row class. And explain us why you want to do that. Going from a list of typed objects to an array of arrays of string seems backwards to me.

Comment: btw you seem to just be creating new empty arrays `new String[i][j]` and assigning them to `tableArray` so this does not make any sense

Comment: your code makes no sense, you are not even using the `Row r`. This array could be created without the `List`

Comment: @JBNizet I need to convert from an Arraylist of objects to a 2-dimensional array so i can display the arraylist in a JTable.

Comment: Then it really makes no sense to transform it. Create a subclass of AbstractTableModel that reads the data directly from the list of rows.

Answer (score 1):

```
final int listSize = list.size();
E[][] darr = new E[listSize][];
for(int i = 0; i < listSize; i++) {
    ArrayList<E> sublist = list.get(i);
    final int sublistSize = sublist.size();
    darr[i] = new E[sublistSize];
    for(int j = 0; j < sublistSize; j++) {
        darr[i][j] = sublist.get(j);
    }
}
```

I found this answer [here](http://bit.ly/10gIaeK).

Comment: Good but I think this student needed to have his errors pointed out instead of getting some code to paste in his homework. Too bad there is code ready to copy/paste for every simple exercise.

Comment: The OP doesn't have a list of lists. He has a list of Rows.